# How to alternate css files on clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a project. At a certain point i want to have two buttons, one for changing to a lighter theme and another to change to a darker theme and apply the changes to the whole website and not just the page in question

This is the page where i have the functionality:

ConfLayout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>TekSell</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="~/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/styles-admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body id="top">

    <section id="banner">
        <div class="inner">

            <a href="#main" class="more">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Main1 -->
    <div id="main">
        <p style="text-align:center">Serviços</p>
        <div class="inner">

            <!-- Services -->
            <div class="thumbnails">

                <div class="box">
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Gallery","User")' class="image fit"><img src="~/Content/Images/gallery.jpg" /></a>

                    <div class="inner">
                        <h7>Galeria</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Location","User")' class="image fit"><img src="~/Content/Images/location.jpg" /></a>

                    <div class="inner">
                        <h7>Localização</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main2 -->
    <div class="page">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3 class="section-title">Sobre Nós</h3>
                    <figure><img src="~/Content/Images/logo.jpg" /></figure>

                    <h4>Acerca de nós</h4>
                    <p>Somos uma empresa fictícia de venda de software informático</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3 class="section-title">Âmbito</h3>
                    <h4>Projeto desenvolvido no âmbito da unidade curricular de Laboratório de Desenvolvimento de Software</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3 class="section-title">Configurar página</h3>
                    <h4>Administrador, altere aqui o layout da página</h4>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">Layout Configuration</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('styles.css', 0);">Change to lighter theme</a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('styles-admin.css', 0);">Change to darker theme</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="inner">
            <h7>TekSell</h7>
            <p>Email: teksell@lds.pt</p>


        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/changeLayout.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see i've two css files created. The 'styles.css' is the lighter theme, and 'styles-admin.css' is the darker theme. The functionality is implemented at "div class="dropdown-content"

What happens is, as i have both css files linked, when i run it, by default, the view assumes the darker theme(styles-admin.css).

This is the javascript file i use to try the changes:

```
function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {

    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

    var newlink = document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(cssLinkIndex).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
}
```

What is missing? Am i doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Use CSS variables. Set the default colours in the CSS :root before page load and while clicking on the button try changing the root colours again with the same method

Comment: You don't need any scripts - just use `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {` in your stylesheet - and/or use CSS variables as Saravanan suggests (though they aren't "variables", they're Custom Properties): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: As i could see from the video tutorial(i didn't knew about this), she hasn't any button or any toggle implemented in her page, that is only changed in windows settings, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you include two CSS files with the same selectors inside, the second file will always override the first.

Just use one `<link>` and change its href.

Also, why load jQuery and not use it?

```
<link href="~/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

$("link").attr("href","~/Content/styles-admin.css");
```

Job done!

Comment: "Just use one <link> and change its href." - that will cause a flash of unstyled content. That's bad UX. You can still preload a stylesheet.

Comment: Also, no-one should be using jQuery anymore. Please don't advocate that people use it.

Comment: Why? I like jQuery, it's a nice little toolbox for small projects. It's so much more concise than vanilla JS, especially for Ajax queries. If you don't like it, it doesn't mean other people shouldn't use it.

Comment: With respect, modern "vanilla" JS far succeeds what jQuery brought to the table a decade ago, and the modern `fetch` function is far superior to jQuery's `ajax` function. Please see http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ and https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ and https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery and https://hackernoon.com/you-truly-dont-need-jquery-5f2132b32dd1 and so on...

Comment: @JeremyThille your answer dind't help me. What's the difference between load jQuery and use jQuery? Both don't lead to the same thing?

Comment: jQuery is a toolbox, it's full of useful things. You load the library, then you can do things like `$("#myId")` instead of `document.getElementById("myId")`. And then `$(selector).fadeToggle()`, `$(selector).css({ display : "box", border : "red dashed 1px"})`, see, plenty of useful things, not to mention a ton of plugins for everything. That's why loading the library and not using it afterwards is useless, you might as well not load it in the first place.

Comment: @Dai Fetch is indeed very convenient, I use it all the time. For the rest of jQuery, I far prefer writing `$(className).hide()` than `querySelectorAll(className)` and then write a `for` loop and iterate each element to hide it. jQuery is just more lean, easier and faster to write. also, its incredible collection of plugins makes it so much more productive than vanilla JS. Are you rewriting a carousel every time in pure JS? Come on. But again, I'm only using it for very little things, tests and mini-projects. For manly stuff, I use Angular.

Comment: @JeremyThille `querySelectorAll(className).forEach(e => e.hidden = true)` is almost as short and doesn't require any external dependencies. Fewer dependencies are better (`hidden` is a new DOM property introduced a few years ago).

Comment: And what about carousels? Tooltips?

Answer (score 0):

Use similar way. Preset the theme colours and change the root attribute like this

```js
const colors =['#317EEB', '#6427BA'];
let index = 0;
function changeBackground(){
    index = (index+1)%2;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-color', colors[index]);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #317EEB;
}

.set-background{
  background: var(--main-color);
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

button{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-background">

</div>

<button onClick="changeBackground()">Change color</button>
```